# 他のFormを埋め込んだFormのバリデーション

Tags: php, symfony2

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function build Form(FormBuilderInteface $builder, array($options)
    {
        $builder->add('id')
                ->add('name')
                ->add('tag', new TagType());
    }
    ...
}

class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('id')
                ->name('name');
    }
    ...
}
```

以上のような他のFormを埋め込んだProdutのFormを作りProductEntityとTagEntity内でNotBrank許さないバリデーションを設定しました。しかしながらTagEntityに関しては効かないようです。こういったFormのバリデーションはどのように行うのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

親エンティティ側のフィールドで`Valid`制約を使って下さい。
こうすると、関連する子エンティティのバリデーションが実行されます。

- [Valid](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html)

Comment: ありがとうございました！解決しました。